# Why is this AWS Amplify API blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

This REST API in AWS Amplify is created with the commands found below. Without changing any code in the generated Express function, the post request found below results in the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example-id.execute-api.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/example-path' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The Express function by default contains code to avoid CORS issues under the comment `Enable CORS for all methods` at line `21`. What can be done to allow requests to be passed into the API function?

**Default Express code in app.js (backend)**

```
// Enable CORS for all methods
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
  next()
});

// Example POST method
app.post('/example-path', function(req, res) {
  // Add your code here
  res.json({success: 'post call succeed!', url: req.url, body: req.body})
});
```

**Amplify commands**

```
amplify add api

? Please select from one of the below mentioned services: REST
? Provide a friendly name for your resource to be used as a label for this category in the project: example
? Provide a path (e.g., /book/{isbn}): /example-path
? Choose a Lambda source Create a new Lambda function
? Provide a friendly name for your resource to be used as a label for this category in the project: example
? Provide the AWS Lambda function name: example
? Choose the runtime that you want to use: NodeJS
? Choose the function template that you want to use: Serverless ExpressJS function (Integration with API Gateway)
? Do you want to access other resources in this project from your Lambda function? No
? Do you want to invoke this function on a recurring schedule? No 
? Do you want to configure Lambda layers for this function? No
? Do you want to edit the local lambda function now? No

? Restrict API access Yes
? Who should have access? Authenticated users only
? What kind of access do you want for Authenticated users? create, update, delete
? Do you want to add another path? No

amplify push
```

**Component.js**

```
const apiName = 'example';
const path = '/example-path';
const myInit = {
    body: JSON.stringify({
        example: example,
    })
};

API
.post(apiName, path, myInit)
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response);
});
```

Comment: Does a request from Postman to the same endpoint work? Postman will ignore  CORS and should let you identify if the error really is CORS or not. If it really is a CORS issue then check in the AWS console that an OPTIONS method exists for that  endpoint

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: I can call unauthenticated endpoint, but authenticated ones cause a problem.

Comment: Any solution. I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, you probably don't have an issue with CORS. I just ran into this issue, having my API generated via the cli. It complained about CORS, identically to your error. Once I replaced every environment variable reference (i.e. process.env.NODE_ENV) with their hard coded values and pushed my api, it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look into your CloudWatch logs? You will also getting this CORS Error when something is wrong with your code and an error occour during the runtime.

----------- OR

Did you deploy your Api after pushing it ? Please log in to your AWS Console => API Gateway => choose your API and then

[image]